# How to validate the database after migration

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, database-migration

We have Oracle 11g Database running on Amazon EC2 and trying to migrate it to Amazon RDS. Both source and target is Oracle DB. What will be the best way to validate the tables and data in both source and target after migrating the database. How to make sure that everything is migrated successfully without any data loss.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

create a database link `old_db` to your old database and compare data

```
select * from tab1 minus select * from tab2@old_db union all
select * from tab1@old_db minus select * from tab2@old_db
```

The result of this select must be empty

Select the desired tablenames by

```
select table_name from user_tables
```

and build the select statement above to execute it dynamically table by table, something like

```
declare
  l_found number;
  l_sql   varchar2(500);
begin
  for l_rec in (select table_name from user_tables) loop
    begin
      -- assume a database link OLD_DB exists
      l_sql := 'select 1 from dual where exists (select * from ' ||
               l_rec.table_name || ' minus select * from ' ||
               l_rec.table_name || '@OLD_DB union all ' ||
               'select * from ' || l_rec.table_name ||
               '@OLD_DB minus select * from ' || l_rec.table_name || ')';

      dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);

      execute immediate l_sql
        into l_found;

      dbms_output.put_line('difference found :' || l_rec.table_name);
    exception

      when no_data_found then
        dbms_output.put_line('okay :' || l_rec.table_name);
        -- okay
        null;

      when others then
        -- error (check if table exists, ...)
        dbms_output.put_line('error :' || l_rec.table_name);

    end;
  end loop;
end;
```